# Персональный фаервол в Nod32BE

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Как настроить персональный фаервол в Nod32BE для удаленного рабочего стола?

Здравствуйте, как сделать правило в ПФ в Nod32BE, чтобы доступ был из интернета через удаленный рабочий стол. Из локальной сети доступ есть к этому серверу.

Answer (score 1):

Отключить фаервол NOD32, установить [Comodo firewall](http://www.newestsoft.com/Windows/Security-Privacy/Firewalls/Comodo-Personal-Firewall.html), поставить его на самообучение и при первой попытке разрешить доступ.